# Is there built-in command or macro to open Window Spy?

Tags: autohotkey

Is there built-in AutoHotKey command which opens Autohotkey's ***Window Spy*** window?

If not, is there at least a macro (not dependent on particular screen resolution etc.) to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any built-in commands, but you can run **Window Spy** by:

```
Run, "c:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AU3_Spy.exe"
```

Replace `c:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AU3_Spy.exe` by your path to `AU3_Spy.exe`

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice that Window Spy is standalone `AU3_Spy.exe`. Regarding ahkscript.org – sure, I know that, thanks.

Comment: @miroxlav You are welcome. By the way, SciTE4AutoHotkey contains "Active window info" which I think is better than "Window Spy".